# Acumatica - PrimaryView property doesn't populate on page datasource control

Tags: view, properties, acumatica

I am following instructions to add a Customized page but cannot get any values to populate the PrimaryView property.

I've followed these steps a few times along with Clean/Build project and closing Visual Studio, but nothing is working.  I'm just missing something.

In this order:
1- Created new table in Sql called INMerchandiseGroup with similar makeup as Country table.

2- Defined my graph by creating a PXGraph called MerchandiseGroupMaint.

3- Created axpx page called IN201000 using a ListView control.

4- Bind graph to aspx page by setting datasource TypeName to graph.

5- Generated Data Class through aspx page datasource control, loading new table INMerchandiseGroup, selecting GroupCD and description;  set GroupCD IsKey = true and removed string defaults (""), saved and rebuild

6- Added PXSelect actions (alone and with PXDelete, PXCancel) in graph.

7- !!!Problem!!! I go to Properties for datasource to set PrimaryView and nothing is there to select.

Graph:

```
public class MerchandiseGroupMaint : PXGraph<MerchandiseGroupMaint>
{
    PXCancel<INMerchGroup> Cancel;
    PXSave<INMerchGroup> Save;

    PXSelect<INMerchGroup> MerchandiseGroups;
}

Dataclass:

[System.SerializableAttribute()]
public class INMerchGroup : PX.Data.IBqlTable
{
    #region GroupCD
    public abstract class groupCD : PX.Data.IBqlField
    {
    }
    protected string _GroupCD;
    [PXDBString(10, IsUnicode = true, IsKey = true)]
    [PXDefault]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Group ID")]
    public virtual string GroupCD
    {
        get
        {
            return this._GroupCD;
        }
        set
        {
            this._GroupCD = value;
        }
    }
    #endregion
    #region Description
    public abstract class description : PX.Data.IBqlField
    {
    }
    protected string _Description;
    [PXDBString(256, IsUnicode = true)]
    [PXDefault]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Description")]
    public virtual string Description
    {
        get
        {
            return this._Description;
        }
        set
        {
            this._Description = value;
        }
    }
    #endregion
```

I don't get any error messages...if i manually add the PrimaryView to aspx Source code I get an error that view isn't found.

What am I not doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was so silly, I don't know how i didn't see it.  I was missing the "public" access modifier.

```
public class MerchandiseGroupMaint : PXGraph<MerchandiseGroupMaint>
{
    public PXCancel<INMerchGroup> Cancel;
    public PXSave<INMerchGroup> Save;
    public PXSelect<INMerchGroup> MerchandiseGroups;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A new screen can be configured this way,look maybe missed something
[image]
[To Create a Custom Form Template](https://help-2018r1.acumatica.com/Wiki/(W(6))/ShowWiki.aspx?pageid=8d5edea3-1256-4df8-ad67-0a855ada4a26)